# Offline dictionary program: find both similar words as well as words that begin the same

Tags: python, dictionary, difflib

I've written this offline dictionary program. I want when the user presses a key, this program to go into the database and find a word close to the word entered by the user so far. Or when the user entered a word completely and the word was in the database, the program would display it with its meanings.

For this part everything is going well. Then I want for example when the user entered the word "a", program shows all words in database that starting with "a".

Here is an example of my problem: When we enter "a" all words and meanings that begin with "a" should be displayed. But the program shows something like this:

[image: screenshot]

And here is some of my database with `json` format:

```
{"apple": ["Apple", "apple", "Sib", "Apfel", "Des pommes"], "average": ["Average", "average", "Miangin", "Durchschnitt", "Des pommes"], "acknowledge": ["Acknowledge", "acknowledge", "Tasdigh Kardan", "Zu bestatigen", "Pour reconnaître"], "book": ["Book", "book", "Ketab", "Buch", "Livre"], "banana": ["Banana", "banana", "Mouz", "Bananen", "Bananes"], "beach grass": ["Beach Grass", "beach grass", "Chamane Sahel", "Strandhafer", "herbe de plage"], "cat": ["Cat", "cat", "Gorbe", "Katzen", "chatte"], "certificate": ["Certificate", "certificate", "Govahi Name", "Zertifikat", "certificat"], "declaration of conformity": ["Declaration Of Conformity", "declaration of conformity", "Elamie Entebagh", "Konformitatserklarung", "déclaration de conformité"], "database": ["Database", "database", "Paygah Dade", "Datenbank", "base de données"], "dear colleagues": ["Dear Colleagues", "dear colleagues", "Hamkarane Aziz", "Liebe Mitarbeiterinnen und Mitarbeiter", "Chers collègues"]}
```

In this dictionary we have English, Persian, French and German meanings for each word.

You can see my code below:

```py
import json
import msvcrt
import os 
from difflib import get_close_matches

DataBase = json.load(open("DataBase.json"))

def getMeaning(w):

    w = w.lower()
    n = len(w)

    if w in DataBase:
        return DataBase[w]

    elif len(get_close_matches(w,DataBase.keys(),1,0.3)) > 0:
        close_match = get_close_matches(w,DataBase.keys(),1,0.3)[0]
        print("Not Found!\nCheck The Close Match:\n")
        return DataBase[close_match]

    else:
        print ("Not Found!\n")
        res = [value for key, value in DataBase.items()]
        for i in res:
            for j in i:
                if w in j[0:n].lower(): 
                     print(j)
        return ''

word = '' 
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        temp = msvcrt.getwch()
        word += temp
        os.system('cls')
        print(word)
        print("\n")
        meaning = getMeaning(word)
        for item in meaning:
            print(item)
```

Please note that you must run this program in `CMD` to work correctly, because of `msvcrt.kbhit()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone enters `a`, you're calling `getMeaning` which in turn calls `get_close_matches`. You're then checking if that call has a non-zero-length return value and if it does you do `return DataBase[close_match]`. That's where `getMeaning` ends.

You'll never reach the `else`-part of `getMeaning`, if `get_close_matches` produces results. In the screenshot of your question, we can see the results of user input `a` which make sense like this since `get_close_matches` finds `cat` is similar to `a`.

Disregarding that, you should use [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) if you want to test if a string begins with another string. Also, you don't need `elif` or `else` after the previous `if` or `elif` has a `return` and I have changed the names according to [PEP 8 section Descriptive Naming Styles](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles).

Here is a possible solution, using a filter which only accepts a close match if the letters are the same as in `word`:

```py
from difflib import get_close_matches

database = {"apple": ["Apple", "apple", "Sib", "Apfel", "Des pommes"], "average": ["Average", "average", "Miangin", "Durchschnitt", "Des pommes"], "acknowledge": ["Acknowledge", "acknowledge", "Tasdigh Kardan", "Zu bestatigen", "Pour reconnaître"], "book": ["Book", "book", "Ketab", "Buch", "Livre"], "banana": ["Banana", "banana", "Mouz", "Bananen", "Bananes"], "beach grass": ["Beach Grass", "beach grass", "Chamane Sahel", "Strandhafer", "herbe de plage"], "cat": ["Cat", "cat", "Gorbe", "Katzen", "chatte"], "certificate": ["Certificate", "certificate", "Govahi Name", "Zertifikat", "certificat"], "declaration of conformity": ["Declaration Of Conformity", "declaration of conformity", "Elamie Entebagh", "Konformitatserklarung", "déclaration de conformité"], "database": ["Database", "database", "Paygah Dade", "Datenbank", "base de données"], "dear colleagues": ["Dear Colleagues", "dear colleagues", "Hamkarane Aziz", "Liebe Mitarbeiterinnen und Mitarbeiter", "Chers collègues"]}

def get_meaning(word):

    # Make word case-insensitive
    word = word.lower()

    # Check if word already in database
    if word in database:
        return {word: database[word]}

    # Find possible close matches
    close_matches = get_close_matches(word, database.keys(), 1, 0.3)
    # Filter matches: keep only those which contain the same letters
    close_matches = [
        close_match
        for close_match in close_matches
        if set(close_match) == set(word)
    ]
    # Return close matches if any left
    if close_matches:
        return {
            close_match: database[close_match]
            for close_match in close_matches
        }

    # Return all dictionary entries which start with the word
    return {
        entry: database[entry]
        for entry in database
        if entry.startswith(word)
    }
```

Now `a` doesn't produce `cat` anymore:

```
>>> get_meaning("a")
{'apple': ['Apple', 'apple', 'Sib', 'Apfel', 'Des pommes'], 'average': ['Average', 'average', 'Miangin', 'Durchschnitt', 'Des pommes'], 'acknowledge': ['Acknowledge', 'acknowledge', 'Tasdigh Kardan', 'Zu bestatigen', 'Pour reconnaître']}
```

But `applle` still gets recognizes as `apple`:

```
>>> get_meaning("applle")
{'apple': ['Apple', 'apple', 'Sib', 'Apfel', 'Des pommes']}
```

Alternatively, you could modify argument `cutoff` of your call to [`get_close_matches`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) for different results.

Answer (score 1):

In `get_close_matches` optional argument `cutoff` is a float in the range `[0, 1]`.
Possibilities that don’t score at least that similar to word are ignored.

So i just need to change the `cutoff` of `get_close_matches` from `0.3` to `0.8`.
That solves my problem.

```
    elif len(get_close_matches(w,DataBase.keys(),1,0.8)) > 0:
        close_match = get_close_matches(w,DataBase.keys(),1,0.8)[0]
        print("Not Found!\nCheck The Close Match:\n")
        return DataBase[close_match]
```

Comment: Even better if it was that simple :)